# Puzzling... MSNBC.com does not display in Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser

This isn't a development question but I'm hoping with all the smart minds someone will know what's up.

When I try to retrieve `www.msnbc.com` in Firefox 10.0.2, it does not display. The title bar changes to the live title, when I `View Source` I see all the code up until the very last line . But the page is never drawn.

The status bar sometimes hangs on `Transferring data from b.scorecardresearch.com...` and sometimes on `Transferring data from www.google-analytics.com` other times on `Read from www.google-analytics.com`. If I hit `Esc` to stop the browser, nothing loads.

When I try to retrieve the site in any other browser (current distribution of Chrome, Safari, IE9) it loads within seconds.  I do not have this same problem with any other websites I visit.

Anyone have any thoughts?

I'm using these browser extensions:

- Blank Canvas Signatures for Gmail 1.17.2b
- ColorZilla 2.6.4
- Download Statusbar 0.9.10
- FaviconizeTab 1.0.6
- Firebug 1.9.1
- FireShot 0.96
- oldbar 1.2
- Session Manager 0.7.8.1
- Switch to Tab no more 0.1
- User Agent Switcher 0.7.3
- Web Developer 1.1.9

Windows 7 x64 Ultimate

Comment: Got the same version of FF and works for me, so there must be something within your modules, or maybe your proxy. So disable all modules and add back one by one.

Comment: Restart in Safe Mode and it loaded up. Guess there's a conflict with one of the add-ons. Thanks Michael. Sorry to take up your extremely important time, Warren </sarcasm>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conflict with one of my installed extensions: FireBug.